# CentOS 6 Partitioning Root Drive

Tags: centos, partition, hard-disk, split

I have recently installed CentOS (into a machine with only one hard drive) and I would like to know how to Partition the main hard drive into two.

As it is a fresh install there is no data to lose and I am using linux rescue from a live CD

```
 50GB
[/dev/sda            ]

 25GB       25G
[/dev/sda1][/dev/sda2]
```

These are bogus numbers at the moment and I doubt the result will be what I expect but anything close or any ideas would be really great

Answer (score 2):

You can easily partition it into `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` with `fdisk`, `parted`, `gparted`, or another partitioning tool (if you're working from a live CD) or via Anaconda (if you're in the Anaconda installer).

Comment: I will be using linux rescue from a live CD

Comment: In a rescue environment (note this is different from the installer), you will want to use one of the paritioning tools available. I usually use `fdisk`.

Comment: I know I need to use fdisk but would I not do damage to the system by partitioning the main hard drive?

Comment: Your live system is running from the CD. Any data on the hard drive will be removed (obliterated, gone forever) when you partition the drive - no matter what tool you use. If you need to preserve the data on the hard drive now, you must back it up to another drive or device first.

Answer (score 2):

If you partition the drive /dev/sda you will get as result two partitions, not drives
/dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2

To partition it now you will need a lot of details. Will be better to back your data and start with new installation. And in the process of install select manual disk partitioning and split the disk

Comment: It is a completely fresh installation, if i get two partitions then that's fine

Comment: If its fresh install. Start it from the begin again. And select from installation steps to do manual partitioning. And create the partitions you need. Will be good to have one (= size of the RAM) partition for swap. Then assign 1st 25G partition to / (root), assign (if you create it) small to swap and continue. The installer is graphical and not so complex

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing it through the installer because once I have it partitioned I will be doing the same thing to other machines where reinstalling won't be an option

Comment: As mentioned in other question you can use http://gparted.org/livecd.php boot from this CD and shrink big partition and create second from unallocated disk space. But be aware (as far as I know) you can't shrink mounted partition so you will need downtime